# Unity Game Level Managment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on developing a Car Parking game using Unity and C#. I'm seeking assistance with implementing a Level Manager to handle various aspects of the game's levels. The Level Manager will be responsible for tracking and managing the following properties associated with each level:

1. Level Locked: Indicates whether a level is inaccessible or locked for the player.
2. Level Unlocked: Signifies that a level has been made accessible to the player by meeting certain conditions or completing previous levels.
3. Current Level: Represents the level the player is currently on.

My main query is how to effectively track and store the level information within Unity. I want to be able to determine which levels the player has played, which ones are unlocked, and the player's progress in terms of the current level.

I have tried using PlayerPrefs, but I am unable to track a good record from that, so is there anyone to help me building my logic about that how I can implement it effieciently.

Comment: In 2 words Scriptable Objects

Comment: Unity provides details about setting this kind of thing up here: https://unity.com/how-to/architect-game-code-scriptable-objects including examples.

Comment: @DevAm00 since the type is `ScriptableObject` it might even be only one ^^ Note though: `ScriptableObject` are no solution for keeping track of progress across sessions! They are more meant to be data containers for different settings etc not for persistent data changed on runtime

Comment: `I have tried using PlayerPrefs, but I am unable to track a good record from that` ..what exactly have you tried? I would probably rather go with some binary save file - maybe even add some encryption to make it a bit more difficult .. if you fully want to avoid cheating you won't really come around using some remote server solution. Everything can and will be hacked eventually, the question is how much effort shall it cost

Comment: exactly your level system should be a mix between scriptable objects : easier to generate and make levels and save system :  to handle unlocked levels  and current level progress 

Pro tip : no one knows what is better for your game there are hundreds of systems for implementing levels you need to try what is best for you game :)